# Drupal - Update Statistics label from "read" to "view" and "reads" to "views"

Tags: theming

As the subject suggests I'm attempting to update the statistics title via a theme_preprocess_node function to read 'views' instead of 'reads':

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node($variables) {

  $content = $variables['content'];
  // Check the node  type to make sure
  // we have the one we want

  $content['links']['statistics']['#links']['statistics_counter']['title'] = str_replace('reads', 'views', $content['links']['statistics']['#links']['statistics_counter']['title']);
}
```

This isn't working but I cannot see why. 
I also don't want to use the stringoverrides module as I use 'read' and 'reads' elsewhere on the site.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you aren't accepting `$variables` by reference, so you're just changing a local variable. This will probably do what you want:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $content = &$variables['content'];

  // Check the node  type to make sure
  // we have the one we want

  $content['links']['statistics']['#links']['statistics_counter']['title'] = str_replace('reads', 'views', $content['links']['statistics']['#links']['statistics_counter']['title']);
}
```

Comment: Any idea how I can I can cover both the non-plural ('read'->'view') as well?

Comment: Drupal's got a handy little function for that, [`format_plural()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_plural/7). The docs should make it fairly obvious how to use it but if not just chuck another question up and someone'll tell you what to do :)